# Restart Current scene in cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am wondering what is the proper way to restart the current scene in cocos2d since I can´t get it working properly. I am using the following code to restart the actual scene, but only a black screen appears....

```
CCScene *currentScene = [CCDirector sharedDirector].runningScene;
CCScene *newScene = [[[currentScene class] alloc] init];

[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:0.7f scene:newScene]];
```

Note: I don´t know if this has something to do with the fact (I guess not) that this code is run from a CClayer subclass that is in charge of managing the pause menus and stuff.

Note2: this is a generic re-start and I pretend it to work with every scene, so I
Thanks!!

Comment: check for memory leaks or overreleasing object (enable zombies)

Comment: There are no memory leaks or overrelasing objects, and I´ve just found the problem : [currentScene class] is returning CCScene instead of the name of the custom class. Thats why I see a black screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For others that are experiencing the same problem, this is the way I found to overcome the issue:

```
    Class SceneClass = NSClassFromString(nameOfClass);
[[CCDirector sharedDirector]replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:[SceneClass scene]]];
```

Where nameOfClass is a string that contains the name of the class that implements the scene to restart. This way works like a charm and you don´t even have to #import the .h file.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it has something to do with that manual alloc. In most cases, it's better to call cocos2d static constructors, and let it handle the memory management for you. This is what I do.-

```
MyClassScene *newScene = [MyClassScene node];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:kTransitionTime scene:newScene withColor:ccc3(255, 255, 255)]];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I get the exact same result. The thing here is that this is a generic re-start and I pretend it to work with every scene, so that´s why I call CCScene *currentScene = [CCDirector sharedDirector].runningScene; to know which scene is running at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CCScene *currentScene = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene];

[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:0.7f scene:[currentScene node]]];
```

Comment: [CCScene node] produces a warning and then the app crashes:
reason: '-[CCScene node]: unrecognized selector